# How can I 'translate' all unicode codes in a string to the actual symbols using Python 3?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, urllib, non-ascii-characters

I'm parsing web content to isolate the body of news articles from a certain site, for which I'm using urllib.request to retrieve the source code for the article webpage and isolate the main text. However, urllib takes characters like "ç" and puts it into a python string as its utf-8 notation, "c387". It does the same for the '”' and "„" characters, which print as an 'e' followed by a set of numbers. This is very irritating when trying to read the article and thus needs to be resolved. I could loop through the article and change every recognizable utf-8 code to the actual character using a tedious function, but I was wondering if there was a way to do that more easily.

For an example, the current output of my program might be:
`e2809eThis country doesn't...e2809d`

I would like it to be:
`„This country doesn't...”`

*Note: I've already checked the source code of the web page, which just uses these 'special' characters, so it's definitely a urllib issue.*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

urllib returns bytes:

```
>import urllib
>url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62085906'
>data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
>type(data)
bytes
>idx = data.index(b'characters like')
>data[idx:idx+20]
b'characters like "\xc3\xa7"'
```

Now, let's try to interpret this as utf-8:

```
>data[idx:idx+20].decode('utf-8')
'characters like "ç"'
```

Et voilà!